# onPostExecute getting null Json

Tags: php, android, json, authentication

I want to pass data from `RegisterActivity` to `mySqlDatabase`, using a new class called `BackgroundTask` (which extends AsyncTask). After `onPreExecute()`, `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` are called, `onPostExecute` is getting a `null` value to my attribute JSON.

**BackGroundTask**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
String registerUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/gestion/register.php";
Context ctx ;
Activity activity ;
ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
AlertDialog.Builder builder ;
public BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    activity = (Activity)ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait ");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting Server ... ");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(registerUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String name = params[1];
            String email = params[2];
            String password = params[3];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                          URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                          URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder =  new StringBuilder();
            String line  =  "" ;
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
  if(json == null){
      try {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          showDialog("Registration Failed ", "Json Null" , "reg_false" );
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
          JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
          JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
          String code = jo.getString("code");
          String message = jo.getString("message");
          if(code.equals("reg_true")){
              showDialog("Registration sucess ", message , code );
          }else if(code.equals("reg_false")){
              showDialog("Registration Failed ",message,code);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }else{
      showDialog("Registration Failed ", "Json not  Null" , "reg_false" );
  }
}

public void showDialog(String title ,  String message, String code ){
    builder.setTitle(title);
    if(code.equals("reg_true")|| code.equals("reg_false")){
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

**RegisterActivity**

```
 public void initGUI(){
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    conPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_con_password);
    register =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    initGUI();

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (name.getText().toString().equals("") || email.getText().toString().equals("")  || password.getText().toString().equals("")|| conPassword.getText().toString().equals("")){
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Mooooochkila 1 ");
                builder.setMessage(" walm3alam 3amar kolchi ola may3bak hal");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Wakha", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }

                );
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
            else if (!(password.getText().toString().equals(conPassword.getText().toString()))){
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Mooooochkila 2 ");
                builder.setMessage("3awati lpassword Ghalet 3awd 4awdo");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Wakha", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                password.setText("");
                                conPassword.setText("");
                            }
                        }

                );
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            else{
                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(RegisterActivity.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("register", name.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think there might be problem in your server url.

Answer (score 0):

Put 10.0.2.2 in your url if you are using the default android emulator for testing, or 10.0.3.2 if you are using the genemotion emulator. The 127.0.0.1 is your loopback or localhost address. But you need to put the address of you emulator or PC.